# BufferedReader reads line only after closing the connection, not after flush()

Tags: java

I've the following `Server.java`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(12345);
        Socket client = server.accept();
        OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(out));
        writer.write("Hello client");
        writer.flush(); //After executing of that instruction there is no any output on the client
        client.close(); //The client prints "Hello client"
    }
}
```

and the `Client.java`:

```
public class Main {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(r.readLine());
        s.close();
    }
}
```

The issue is I can't get the reason why the client prints the string only after the connection was closed, but not after the stream was flushed. I thought `flush()` send a signal to the client that data-transfering process is over. Since, the client have to read all the data that was being send to it before calling `flush()`. What's wrong?

Comment: client is trying to read a line. but  writer.write("Hello client"); doesn't append any new line char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

readLine() reads a complete line. To know that the line is complete, the reader needs to either find a newline character sequence, or the end of the stream. So it blocks until it sees one of those.

Realize that your client might very well do the following:

```
out.write("Hello ");
out.flush();
out.write("world!\n");
out.flush();
```

This sends a single line: "Hello world". And `readLine()` as its name indicates, is supposed to return that, not 2 lines "Hello " and "World".

So, if you want to send a line, you need to end its line terminator. Otherwise you're not sending a line, but only some characters.

Note that it would be easier if you used a PrintWriter correctly:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())));
out.println("Hello client");
```